# Write RSS for wordpress with custom fields

Tags: wordpress, rss

I want to manually write my rss and use it to import posts into several blogs i have

```
<item>
<title>testin</title>
<description>hello</description>
<custom field????    
</item>
```

How to add a custom field to be seen by wordpress?

Is there a free soft which i can use to write rss quicklier?

TY!

Comment: What do you mean by "seen by wordpress"? What plugin/function are you using to import the data?

Comment: The clasis wordpress importer.. from rss

Comment: I just want to add a field in my rss which wordpress will see it as custom field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want WordPress to "see" it, you will have to convert your xml into structs that match what WordPress is expecting for newPage, newComment, newCategory etc... you can see the struct parameters as well as return values here...

[WordPress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp)